# Java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range 2> 1

Tags: java, mysql

I have been getting this error and I don't know what is causing it.

This is a simple email auto reply java that I came up with. I will connect to a database which has two columns in the table. rEmail and sEmail, receiver ... sender.

So if the receiver and sender matches the check that I have done for my java code.. it will auto reply an email but I kept getting this SQL error which I have no idea what is it about.. Below is my codes..

```
public class TestList
  extends TestMatch
{

  private Collection senders;

  public void init()
    throws MessagingException
  {

  }

  public Collection match(Mail mail) throws MessagingException
  {
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try
{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mail", "root", "password");

  stmt = conn.createStatement();

  String receiver = mail.getRecipients().toString();
  String sender = mail.getSender().toString();

  String receiverResult = receiver.substring(receiver.indexOf("[") + 1, receiver.indexOf("]"));

  String sql = "SELECT senderEmail FROM TestList where rEmail='"+ rResult +"'" + " AND sEmail='"+sender+"'";
  System.out.println("SQL ERROR Here -- 31");

  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

  this.senders = new HashSet();
  while (rs.next()) {
    this.senders.add(new MailAddress(rs.getString("sEmail")));
  }

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close(); 
}
catch (SQLException se)
{
  se.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
  try
  {
    if (stmt != null) {
      stmt.close();
    }
  }
  catch (SQLException se2) {}
  try
  {
    if (conn != null) {
      conn.close();
    }
  }
  catch (SQLException se)
  {
    se.printStackTrace();
  }
}   
    System.out.println("SQL ERROR Here -- 72);
if (this.senders.contains(mail.getSender())) {  
    System.out.println("SQL ERROR Here -- 74");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        System.out.println("auto reply");
        msg.setSubject ("subject");
        msg.setSender (new InternetAddress("Postmaster@test.com"));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,(new InternetAddress("user1@captcha.com")));
        msg.setText ("describe the mail text of","utf-8","Plain");
        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("e-mail sent.");

  return mail.getRecipients();
} else {
return null;
}
  }
}
```

This thing will run twice, and I do not know exactly why also. At first everything will go smoothly until email sent and then it will repeat once more and stop at SQL error --72.

I have been trying to figure this out for days so can someone please help?

===== UPDATE NEW ERROR after using rs.getString(1) or rs.getString(2);

```
`SQL ERROR Here -- line 31
 java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5570)
    at org.apache.james.transport.matchers.SenderIsGreyList.match(SenderIsGreyList.java:59)
    at org.apache.james.transport.LinearProcessor.service(LinearProcessor.java:357)
    at org.apache.james.transport.JamesSpoolManager.process(JamesSpoolManager.java:405)
    at org.apache.james.transport.JamesSpoolManager.run(JamesSpoolManager.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
SQL ERROR Here -- line 72`
```

Comment: Use prepared Statements. It is easier to read and much more safty

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: I believe the stack trace is showing that the error is occurring with in the rs.getString. There is only one column being returned, so an `rs.getString(2)` would throw this exception. But an `rs.getString(1)` shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're attempting to retrieve column named "sEmail" from rows in the resultset...

```
  rs.getString("sEmail")
```

But your query doesn't return a column of that name. The SELECT statement returns a column named "senderEmail".

I always use numeric.  Use 1 to get the first column, e.g.

```
  rs.getString(1)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry that was my error for the select statement. I changed it to sEmail. I am using numeric now and this is what I am getting, it is not even going past the first first sql error at line 31 now. Check above for update..

Comment: I recommend you output se.getErrorCode and se.getSQLState in the exception handler, to see what error MySQL is returning. There's any number of things it could be... insufficient privileges, the table doesn't exist (tablename is case-sensitive?), the columns don't exist in the table... all sorts of things could be going on. We also note that the code appears vulnerable to SQL Injection. Is there a reason you aren't using a prepared statement with bind placeholders? Also, what is `rResult` (included in the SQL text)? Where is that coming from?

Comment: The usual cause for this error is attempting an `rs.getString(N)` or `rs.getInt(N)` using a value of N that is larger than the number of columns returned by the SELECT statement.

Comment: Thank you spencer, I found out my mistake, its because I couldn't find anything in the database, its empty and thats why there is problem with the SQL. Thank you!